# Property 'jumpservice' does not exist on type 'PaperDocuments'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, angular2-routing

- I am new to angular 2 and typescript.
- I am facing the below erros in my code.
- I googled for the error and they asked to include the import statements.
- but still the error is not going.
- can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- providing code and error below.
- am I missing something
- i tried all the possible solutions

```or-tag-here
///<reference path="../../../assets/js/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
import {NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,Component, ElementRef, Inject, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Http,HttpModule, Response,Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {KendoGridComponent} from '../grid/grid.component';
//import { TranslateService } from '../../translate/translate.service';
import { SPORTSService } from '../../services/sports.service';
import {jumpService} from '../jump/jumpService';


import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
declare let $:any;



@Component({
    selector: 'PaperDocuments',
    template: `<div id="windowcontainer"></div>`
})


export class PaperDocuments {

    @ViewChild(KendoGridComponent) private gridmobile: KendoGridComponent;
    private dataSourceVal;
    private MainGrid;
    private grid;
    private isVisible = false;
    public toggleCollapse : string;
    private kPopUpWindowViewHistory;
    private fileName;
    private scrollClicked;
    private dynamicnetwks;

        /*Localization*/
    public show: string;
    public all: string;
    public entries: string;
    public cancelBtn: string;
    public okBtn: string;
    public attachBtn:string;
    public elfBtn: string;
    public browseBtn:string;
    public dragDrop: string;
    public clearBtn:string;
    public attachmentType:string;
    public fileSelect:string;


    private Type = ["PRM", "STR","FRT", "Urban Legends"];
    private isDone: boolean = true
    private filesToUpload: Array<File>;
    private files = [];
    private url = "http://localhost:3002/upload";
    private dialogCommand;
    public encodeBase64:any;
    public isContractLocked=false;
    private loggedUserName;
    private documentType='';
    public elfDocIDTemp;
    public openFlag = false;
    private selectedoptions;
    //private fileSelected = false;

    private mobilecommand = {
        edit: {
          createAt: "bottom"
        },
        group: true,
        reorder: true,
        resize: true,
        sort: true,
        autoBind: false,
        filter: {
          mode: "menu"
        },
        pager: {
          messages: {
            display: "Showing {0} to {1} of {2} entries"
          }
        },
        model: {},
        columns: [],
        pagesize: 50,
        getComponentUrl: "jumps/v1/jumps/35355?includes=payments",
        postComponentUrl: "jumps/v1/jumps/35355?includes=payments",
        excelfileUidName: "ViewPaymentExport",
        isLevels: false,
        excelFileName: {
          fileName: "ViewPaymentExport",
          allPages: true
        },
        contextMenuId: "context-menuAllocation",
        navigate: false,
        data: "",
        mandatoryFields: [],
        disableFreeze: true,
        searchFields: [],
        defaultSort: []
     };

    constructor(public sportsService : SPORTSService ){

    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.documentType='Contract';
        this.privilegeSettings();

        let that=this;


        this.jumpservice.reloadDocumentEventReceived.subscribe(documents=>{
                that.documentType="Contract";
                $('.addELFDocumentForm').hide();
                that.isDone = true;
                that.dragDrop= that.clearBtn;
                $("#attachDocumentBrowseBtn").val('');
                if(documents.isReLoad){
                    this.mobilecommand.getComponentUrl='jumps/v1/jumps/'+documents.data+'?includes=documents';//
                    that.gridmobile.getServiceCall(documents.data);

                }else{
                that.rowDotMenuClick({"selectedMenuItem":"setData","type":"normalService","data":documents.data});
                }               
        });


        this.mobilecommand.model={
                id: "documentId",
                fields: {
                    contextRow:{editable:false,filterable:true},
                    docId:{editable:true,filterable:false,sortable:false},
                    documentName: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    //elfDocID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    elfDocID: { 
                    validation: { 
                        required: true,
                        digits:true                                                         
                    }                                                                               
                },
                    url: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    documentType: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    date: { editable: false, nullable: true }
                }
        };  

        this.mobilecommand.columns=[
                                { 
                                    field: "contextRow", width: 25, title:" ",
                                    template:""/*'<span class="contextMenuRow" id="contextMenuRowid"></span>'*//*"<span class='fa fa-file docIcon' id='dcms'></span>"*/
                                },
                                { 
                                    field: "docId", width: 25, title:" ",sortable:false,
                                    /*template:"<span class='documentIcon displayInlineBlock'></span>"/*,*/

                                    template: function name(model) {
                                        return that.ImageType(model);
                                    },
                                    editor:function (container,model){
                                        that.docTemplateEditor(container,model,that);
                                    }
                                }
                            ];

    }

    privilegeSettings():void{
        let userPrivilege = this.sportsservice.getUserPrivilege({"parent":"Contract Management","child":"Documents"})
        if(userPrivilege == "Full"){
            this.isContractLocked = false;
        }else{
            this.isContractLocked = true;
        }
    }

    running(values):void{
        let that = this;
        $("#windowcontainer").append(`<div class="allocationViewHistoryPopUpBox">

            <div id="viewHistoryPopUpWindow" class="mobilepobUpBox">
                <div class="row mobilePopUpHeader">
                    <div class="mobilePopUpHeaderTitleBox">
                        <h4 class="">Documents</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mobilePopUpHeaderActionsBox">
                        <button class="clearBtn triggerKPopUpClickViewHistory" type="button" id="closePopup">CLOSE</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearFloat"></div>

                <div class="row mobilePopUpGridCollection padBottom0Imp">
                    <div id="popup-loading"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 pad0Imp borderHistoryGridTop">
                        <div id="viewHistoryPopUpGrid" class="kGridStaticFilter"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearFloat"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearFloat"></div>

                <label class="commonLink cursorPointer  vAlignTop lineHeightInputs" (click)="browseButton()" id="forAttachDocumentBrowseBtn" [class.disabled]="isContractLocked">BROWSE{{browseBtn}}</label>
            </div>





            </div>`);

        let viewHistoryPopUpGrid =[];

        that.dataSourceVal = new mobile.data.DataSource( {
            transport: {
                read: function(e) {
                    e.success(viewHistoryPopUpGrid);
                }
            },
            sort: true,
            group: [{field: values.group}]
            //ignoreCase: false //<--ignore the casing will stop applying .toLowerCase()
        //  filter: "gte" //<-- filter operator compliant with `number` type
        });

        that.MainGrid = {
            dataSource: that.dataSourceVal,
            reorderable:true,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: {mode:"row, menu"},
            dataBound:function(e){
               let   gridDataSource = e.sender.dataSource;
               console.log('history',e)
                    if (gridDataSource.group().length > 0) {
                        $("#collapseBtn123").removeClass('actionDisabled')
                    }else{
                        that.toggleCollapse="COLLAPSE ALL";
                        $('#collapseBtn123').text(that.toggleCollapse);
                        $("#collapseBtn123").addClass('actionDisabled')
                    }
              },
            groupable:true,
            editable: false,
            columns: values.columns,
            pageable:{messages: {display: "Showing {0} to {1} of {2} entries"}},
            pageSize:50,
        };

        that.kPopUpWindowViewHistory = $("#viewHistoryPopUpWindow");

        // $("#closePopup").click(function(){
        //  that.closePopup();
        //  console.log("click");
        // });

        // $("#collapseBtn123").click(function(){
        //    that.collapseBtn();   
        // });

        that.kPopUpWindowViewHistory.mobileWindow({
                        width: "80%",
                        title: false,
                        visible: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        actions: false,
                        draggable: false,
                        modal: true,
                        ignoreCase: false, //<--ignore the casing will stop applying .toLowerCase()
                        filter: "gte", //<-- filter operator compliant with `number` type
                        open:function(e) {
                            let windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight();
                            //let popupHeight = $('.k-widget.k-window').outerHeight();
                            let popupHeight = 500;
                            console.log(windowHeight, popupHeight);
                            if(popupHeight < windowHeight) {
                                $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
                            } else {

                            }
                        },

                        close: function(e) { 
                            $("html, body").css("overflow", ""); that.isVisible=false; 
                        },

                        deactivate: function() {
                            this.destroy();   
                            console.log("deactivate Call");                             
                        }

                        // closePopup: function() {
                     //     this.kPopUpWindowViewHistory.data("mobileWindow").close();
                        // }

        });

        that.kPopUpWindowViewHistory.data("mobileWindow").center();         
        that.kPopUpWindowViewHistory.data("mobileWindow").open();

        $(".k-window").css("top", "15%");

        // closePopup(): void {
        //      //this.isVisible = false;
        //      this.kPopUpWindowViewHistory.data("mobileWindow").close();
        //  }


    }

}




-MacBook-Pro:webapp Raj$ npm start

> SPORTS@1.0.0 start /Users/Raj/Desktop/nbc/webcomponent/src/main/webapp
> tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" 

app/components/skys/sky-documents.ts(129,8): error TS2339: Property 'jumpservice' does not exist on type 'PaperDocuments'.
app/components/skys/sky-documents.ts(140,10): error TS2339: Property 'rowDotMenuClick' does not exist on type 'PaperDocuments'.
app/components/skys/sky-documents.ts(200,23): error TS2339: Property 'ImageType' does not exist on type 'PaperDocuments'.
app/components/skys/sky-documents.ts(203,16): error TS2339: Property 'docTemplateEditor' does not exist on type 'PaperDocuments'.
app/components/skys/sky-documents.ts(211,28): error TS2339: Property 'sportsservice' does not exist on type 'PaperDocuments'.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! SPORTS@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the SPORTS@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Raj/.npm/_logs/2017-07-26T03_44_36_683Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the  **`jumpservice`** to your constructor

```
constructor(public sportsService : SPORTSService, private _jumpService : jumpService ){
}
```

and use it as,

**`this._jumpService`**

Comment: The same way you need to check for other variables whehter you have declared them. Also do a clean and restart the app

Comment: Hi... can you tell me which variables??

Comment: app/components/skys/sky-documents.ts(129,8): error TS2339: Property 'jumpservice' does not exist on type 'PaperDocuments'.
app/components/skys/sky-documents.ts(140,10): error TS2339: Property 'rowDotMenuClick' does not exist on type 'PaperDocuments'.
app/components/skys/sky-documents.ts(200,23): error TS2339: Property 'ImageType' does not exist on type 'PaperDocuments'.
app/components/skys/sky-documents.ts(203,16): error TS2339: Property 'docTemplateEditor' does not exist on type 'PaperDocuments'.
app/components/skys/sky-documents.ts(211,28): err

Comment: the above ones needs to be declared